# Mouse click firing twice

Tags: xubuntu, mouse

I have recently switched to XUbuntu (14.04) and I have noticed that sometimes a mouse click is fired twice.

E.g. I CTRL click a link and two tabs with the same content are opened in my browser. It's not behaviour I can reproduce consistently and seems to be random (to me). I also don't know of a good way to inspect the behaviour properly for debugging purposes. I have checked the double click time setting but this doesn't seem to have any impact on this.

I also run XUbuntu (13.10) in a VM on my MacBook Air and this behaviour seems to absent there. At this point in time I can't really tell if this is related to the distribution or the fact that it runs in a VM.

Any insights greatly appreciated.

Comment: May not beyour case, but it happened to me two times in the last three years; both times was a hardware problem, so before going digging on the sw double check your mouse is ok. My second one was fixed by blowing in it with a bottle of compressed air...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I assume you refer to the mouse it self? I will try changing it for another for a while and see what happens.

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for the tip. It definitely seems to have made a difference. It must have been pure coincidence that the weekend I switched my desktop over from Ubuntu Gnome to XUbuntu that my mouse gave up on me (it's a few years old). If you add you comment as an answer I will except it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The multiple click problem has happened to me a couple of times since now; in both cases was a faulty mouse. My opinion is that the quality of the switches in most modern mice is at least questionable.

1. Check the mouse in another machine with (possibly) another operating system.
2. If you can, try to blow the mouse interior with compressed air (there are electronic-grade bottles around). That solved my problems once.
3. If the problem persist just on your computer/operating system, now it's time to search for a software problem.